# Joomla4 JRequest::setVar replacement

Tags: php, joomla

I'm using a 3rd party component that is not updated to the last version of Joomla.
It still uses JRequest:

```
JRequest::setVar('view', 'controlpanel');
```

Can somone help me to replace this call?
Thank you all
Daniele

Comment: Please always ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  [Replacing JRequest (deprecated) with JInput](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/17738/12352) and [Replacement of JRequest::getVar('return', '', 'method', 'base64')](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/17603/12352) and [Upload single or multiple files replacing deprecated JRequest::getVar('file', '', 'files', 'array');](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/30346/12352)

Comment: [Example form on posting data through JInput class](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/18116/12352) and from the forum: [Replace JRequest::getVar](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=980956)